# How to update an unidirectional ManyToMany mapping in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have been searching for an answer now for several hours and I can't find a clean solution by myself.

I have an entity called "Tag". You can add these tags to nearly everything, f.e. to an article, a news and so on. Therefor my entites (in this example an article) refer to these tags with an unidirectional ManyToMany mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tag2article",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $tags;
```

This relation is unidirectional, because then I don't want to have an articleTag, a newsTag etc. or several entities as joinTables. The doctrine manual calls unidirection ManyToMany relations "less common", because you can build such relations as 3 entities with an additional joinTableEntity. But this would result in too much entities of this kind.

When I create an article, these tags are added by:

```
foreach ($tagArray as $tagId) {
        $tag = $entityManager->getRepository('myBundle:Tag')->findOneById($tagId);
        if ($tag != null) {
            $article->addTag($tag);
        }
    }
$entityManager->persist($article);
$entityManager->flush();
```

This works fine on insert. On update I do the same, but it doesn't work and I don't know why. The only solutions I found was to add this article to the tag, but this isn't possible though I am working with an unidirectonal relation.

In my ArticleForm, I just have a hidden field:

```
->add('tags', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => '',
                'property_path' => false
            ))
```

In this way I can add tags pretty easy with Ajax and write these tagIds in this hidden field.

**My overall question is:** Why does this way work on insert, but not on update? What can I do to fix this?

Many thanks for your help or any hints!!

Comment: What happens when you edit the article and submit a valid form?

Comment: You say "on update it doesn´t work" and "I add this article to the tag, but it isn´t possible". What happens in each case? Can you be more specific?

Comment: If I edit the article, all changes are saved correctly, for example the name of the article or the content.
I added the tags to the article and I also testet if these are realy applied to the article and they are. I can get all these tags by $article->getTags(); but if I persist it, they aren't updated.

Comment: Nobody a clue @Gremo or @Carlos?